# Flutter Login Screen

Tags: flutter, dart

```
   Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple
                    *border*: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'E-mail adresinizi giriniz'
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

**I get this errors. Can someone help?**

*Expected to find ','.

**I know I should add ','. But where?**

***Underlined word marked***

Comment: refer to how to ask a question please, i think you forgot a comma after the  color: Colors.deepPurple line

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that by the time it reached `border`, it was expecting a `,`.

The compiler / analyzer / linter won't always be able to tell you exactly where your issue is, but in this case it's pretty close (hint: the line before `border`).

I'd recommend getting in the habit of including the `,` at the end of ever line when you're splitting parameters over multiple lines, even when you don't need it (i.e. after the last parameter). For example, instead of

```
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'E-mail adresinizi giriniz'
                      )
```

Do

```
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'E-mail adresinizi giriniz',
                      )
```

That way it's easier to notice when it's missing, and if you add new parameters after it, you don't need to remember to add a `,` to it first.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the comma after this section **`color: Colors.deepPurple`**,
inside `BoxDecoration` line number **five**.